# What is edge maximal graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Going through Graph theory ,
i found

> We call Graph $G$ edge Maximal if with a given graph property if $G$ itself has the property but no graph  $G$+$xy$  does for non adjacent vertices $x,y$   $\epsilon$ G

I am not getting what does it really mean .!

please help me out !!!

Comment: It means that $G$ itself has the property, but if you add a new edge to $G$ then it will no longer have the property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A graph with a certain property is called *edge maximal* for that property if you cannot add another edge but keep the property. For instance, a tree is an edge-maximal cycle-free graph. You cannot add an edge while keeping it cycle-free, because adding an edge to a tree always adds a cycle. Similarly, if you graph consists of two components, each of which is a complete graph, then this graph is edge maximal disconnected: adding any edge to the graph turns it into a connected graph.

Comment: This is definitely a concept best explained using examples in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, even better explained using pictures.